# Authorize.Net woocommerce plugin payment issues for sandbox

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment, authorize.net

I am using Authorize.net payment gateway in my wordpress woocommerce site.

I want to have feature like ARB , CIM and subscription, so i got a plugin named `Authorize Net CIM` i have installed it.

I have used sample credit card number but still it giving error `Payment declined` . I have already enabled TEST mode.

So i have 2 question:-

1. Is Authorize Net plugin for subscription is not free ? coz internet has so many plugins free, not able to take out which one to use for ARB,CIM amnd subscriptions.
2. Why i am getting the `payment declied` issue.

Comment: This are the plugins (payment gateways) that work with subscriptions: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/payment-gateways/ .

Comment: @LoicTheAztec: This mean the plugin is not free right?

Comment: **I don't really know about your plugin** *(as you don't give any details and/or links)*. What I know is that list give you all plugins (free or commercial) with the links, that are compatible with WooCommerce Subscriptions. If your plugin is not in that list (linked), may be is not compatible with it, as it is, and you will have to get one from this list.

Comment: This [Authorize](https://woocommerce.com/products/authorize-net-cim/) plugin is not free, but it is guaranteed by Woothemes to work with WooCommerce subscriptions.